# Ubuntu 20.04 HP MFP M281fdw

Tags: hp, scanner

My HP MFP M281fdw scanner does not scan, but printing works.
I use the software document scanner from Ubuntu. If I start the document scanner software it finds three HP devices.

[image]

How can I solve that?

Comment: Thank you, the problem is solved. run "sudo apt-get install hplip-gui" and then start "hp-setup". I had the add the ip address of the printer manually.

Comment: For those users who would prefer not to rely on HPLIP and its non-free plugin and want a modern solution, there is **sane-airscan**. The two ESCL entries and the fact they do not work are bugs in SANE on Ubuntu 20.04 and corrected in 20.10.